# Does ROS source installation variant "mobile" work?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, build-from-source, mobile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Raspberry Pi 3, ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04 (32-bit)

The "robot" variant works fine. But it does not include navigation stack and what I would consider other mandatory packages. So I tried "mobile", like this:

`rosinstall_generator mobile --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-mobile-wet.rosinstall wstool init -j8 src kinetic-mobile-wet.rosinstall`

Result:

```
The following unreleased packages/stacks will be ignored: mobile
No packages/stacks left after ignoring unreleased
```

Which seems to suggest that variant is not working.

Is there a way to add the navigation stack (and other packages) after the fact, into the "robot" variant?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338391/does-ros-source-installation-variant-%22mobile%22-work?/) by [jordan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20512/jordan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2019-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tl;dr: there is no *mobile* variant. So the error you receive would seem to be expected.

---

All variants are defined in [REP 150: ROS Melodic and Newer Metapackages](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0150.html).

For ROS Melodic, they include:

- `ros_core`
- `ros_base`
- `robot`
- `perception`
- `simulators`
- `viz`
- `desktop`, and
- `desktop_full`

`mobile` is not a defined variant.

Where did you see it mentioned?

> it does not include navigation stack and what I would consider other mandatory packages

The navigation packages are not included in any variant. Or at least, not in a variant defined by REP 150.

---

Edit:

> Thanks for pointing out REP 150. I was not aware of that REP, as I was simply following what appears in: http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Source
>
> ie. "In addition to the 3 variants above, more are defined in **REP 131** such as robot..."

Looks like that page needs to be updated for Melodic and should point to REP 150.

> Note that REP 131 DOES include "mobile" (and also navigation!).

Yes, it does.

> I am surprised to find that REP 150 contains no variant that includes navigation. What is the thinking behind that?

I'm not sure. It looks like `mobile` (and some of the other variants) already didn't appear any more in REP-142 (which was submitted in [ros-infrastructure/rep#71](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/71)).

I've tried to find related discussions on the old ROS mailing lists, but nothing really turns up.

Perhaps @tfoote remembers why those variants were removed.

> How should I build from source to include navigation?

The top-level (ie: meta) package for navigation appears to be called [navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) (who'd have thought? ;)).

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
rosinstall_generator --rosdistro=kinetic --tar --deps navigation > navigation.rosinstall
```

That should get you all packages in the `navigation` metapackage.

**But**: please make sure you actually need to build things from source. You state you are running "ROS Melodic, Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit)" on an RPi. If I'm not mistaken, that would be `bionic` on `arm64` (or ARMv8). According to [this page](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_ubv8.html) there are plenty of binary packages available for that combination.

Refer to #q320046 for information on how to figure out when something is available as a binary package, and for which platforms.

---

Edit 2:

> Thanks for the comments and suggestions. Yes, I do indeed actually need to build from source.

As long as you are absolutely sure.

> And I would like the equivalent of "mobile" as specified in REP 131. But regarding your suggestion:

> ```
> rosinstall_generator --rosdistro=kinetic --tar --deps navigation > navigation.rosinstall
> ```

> ... the above just gives me the navigation sources and omits everything else. So, manually merge the two 'src' trees (obtained from variants navigation and base)? Or what?

there is no need to manually do anything. Either:

- ask `wstool` to `merge` in the new `.rosinstall` file, or
- supply `rosinstall_generator` with more package names instead of just the one. Like so:

  ```
   rosinstall_generator --rosdistro=kinetic --tar --deps robot navigation slam_gmapping laser_pipeline perception_pcl > robot_and_navigation.rosinstall
  ```

Refer to the `rosinstall_generator --help` for more information on which combinations of options can be used.

---

Edit 3: I just noticed that you're building Kinetic on Ubuntu Bionic. Could you tell us why?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jordan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20512/jordan/) on 2019-11-23**:
Thanks for pointing out REP 150. I was not aware of that REP, as I was simply following what appears in:

http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Source

ie. "In addition to the 3 variants above, more are defined in **REP 131** such as robot..."

Note that REP 131 DOES include "mobile" (and also navigation!).

I am surprised to find that REP 150 contains no variant that includes navigation. What is the thinking behind that?

How should I build from source to include navigation?

**Comment by [jordan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20512/jordan/) on 2019-11-23**:
Thanks for the comments and suggestions. Yes, I do indeed actually need to build from source. And I would like the equivalent of "mobile" as specified in REP 131. But regarding your suggestion:

```
rosinstall_generator --rosdistro=kinetic --tar --deps navigation > navigation.rosinstall
```

... the above just gives me the navigation sources and omits everything else. So, manually merge the two 'src' trees (obtained from variants navigation and base)? Or what?

**Comment by [jordan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20512/jordan/) on 2019-11-23**:
Sorry. My bad. Too many projects. The platform I'm actually using to test this is:

Raspberry Pi 3, ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04 (32-bit)

I've updated the original wording to reflect that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-23**:
No problem.

Doesn't change my answer.

**Comment by [jordan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20512/jordan/) on 2019-11-23**:
It worked. Thanks for your help!